# Node js callbacks in exported modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a node newbie so forgive me if this is something simple.

I am trying to run a callback once a function has finished. No matter which way around I try it, the callback keeps executing first.

My module import_data.js

```
module.exports.download = function(url, path, supplier, callback) {
//SF add dates to logging
console.log('Import for '+supplier+' started');
request({uri: url})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
    .on('close', function() {
        console.log('Import complete');
    },function(err, data){
        callback;
    });
};
```

import_js is called into common

```
'use strict';

//var db              = require('../config/sequelize').sequelize;

var common              = require('./common/index.js'),
    async               = require('async');

common.importData(
    'www.url.com',
    '/tmp/target.csv', 
    'Target Compenents', 
    console.log('callback')
);
```

I would expect the console.log('calback') to be the last thing logged.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+callbacks

Comment: The return value of `console.log` is `undefined`. So you are currently passing `undefined` to `importData`, not a function. The other issue is that you are never calling `callback`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a function as your callback, *console.log* it's only method it isn't a function which you can use as a callback.
So and to fix it you can wrap your *console.log* into function like below:

```
common.importData(
    'www.url.com',
    '/tmp/target.csv', 
    'Target Compenents', 
    function(){console.log('callback')}
);
```

i hope it will help you thanks!

Comment: They also have to call the callback.

Comment: The anonymous function is a callback in this case am i right ?

Comment: Sure. A function that is passed to another function is a callback. However, the function that the callback is passed to also has to call the callback and that's currently not the case if look at the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

#### Module

```
module.exports.download = function(url, path, supplier, callback) {
  //SF add dates to logging
  console.log('Import for '+supplier+' started');
  request({uri: url})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
    .on('response', function(response) {
      // now it's ready
      callback(response);
    })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

#### App

```
common.download('some_url', 'target.csv', 'Target Components', function(response) {
  console.info(response);
  // ....
});
```